# Does the sequence $\sum_{n=3}^\infty (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(n)}})^{n+1}$ converge or diverge

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Not sure how to about this. Spent a while racking my brain, tried comparison didn't work. I'm thinking I need to show how its similar to a p-series test since its to the power of $n+1$ where $n+1>1$ thus it converges, but not sure how to do that.

Comment: How about $$
\left| { - \frac{1}{{\sqrt {\log n} }}} \right| \le \frac{1}{2}
$$ for $n\geq 55$?